# Troubleshooting HDD formatting mistake and data recovery on Ubuntu 23.04

Tags: ubuntu, data-recovery

I have a Dreambox device with an HDD that was mistakenly formatted. I can access the HDD using the following command:

```
/run/user/1000/gvfs/ftp:host=192.168.xx.xx/media/hdd
```

Now, I would like to know how I can mount the HDD folder to the media folder on Ubuntu 23.04, so that it appears on the disk manager. This way, I can easily search for the folder.

Additionally, what is the best way to recover files and folders with the same name?

Comment: I do not own a dreambox, but it is very unlikely that you can recover your data via network access with ftp. You probably will have to disassemble the box and connect the harddisk to another computer that runs linux. I found a forum entry that describes the steps (in German): https://www.i-have-a-dreambox.com/wbb5/forum/index.php?thread/8462-filesystem-der-hdd-reparieren/&postID=74658#post74658. 
This uses `reiserfsck`.

Comment: I don't have hard drive wire connection to mount it to pc ... So like that I have ask to do it check and recovery from ftp connection with ubuntu ... Also I will look on (Gemini forum)  i-have-a-dreambox.com I'm there also ..

Comment: No chance that you solve a file system recovery via FTP. Try to buy a cheap USB-C to SATA adapter like deleyCON MK4739 or EasyULT X001K6SCTR or similar and connect the harddisk to your pc with Linux.